# Why does numpy.random.dirichlet() not accept multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

On the [numpy page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html) they give the example of

```
s = np.random.dirichlet((10, 5, 3), 20)
```

which is all fine and great; but what if you want to generate random samples from a 2D array of alphas?

```
alphas = np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 3))
```

If you try 
`np.random.dirichlet(alphas)`, 
`np.random.dirichlet([x for x in alphas])`, or 
`np.random.dirichlet((x for x in alphas))`, 
it results in a 
`ValueError: object too deep for desired array`. The only thing that seems to work is:

```
y = np.empty(alphas.shape)
for i in xrange(np.alen(alphas)):
    y[i] = np.random.dirichlet(alphas[i])
    print y
```

...which is far from ideal for my code structure. Why is this the case, and can anyone think of a more "numpy-like" way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.random.dirichlet` is written to generate samples for a single Dirichlet distribution.  That code is implemented in terms of the Gamma distribution, and that implementation can be used as the basis for a vectorized code to generate samples from different distributions.  In the following, `dirichlet_sample` takes an array `alphas` with shape (n, k), where each row is an `alpha` vector for a Dirichlet distribution.  It returns an array also with shape (n, k), each row being a sample of the corresponding distribution from `alphas`.  When run as a script, it generates samples using `dirichlet_sample` and `np.random.dirichlet` to verify that they are generating the same samples (up to normal floating point differences).

```
import numpy as np


def dirichlet_sample(alphas):
    """
    Generate samples from an array of alpha distributions.
    """
    r = np.random.standard_gamma(alphas)
    return r / r.sum(-1, keepdims=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    alphas = 2 ** np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(6, 3))

    np.random.seed(1234)
    d1 = dirichlet_sample(alphas)
    print "dirichlet_sample:"
    print d1

    np.random.seed(1234)
    d2 = np.empty(alphas.shape)
    for k in range(len(alphas)):
        d2[k] = np.random.dirichlet(alphas[k])
    print "np.random.dirichlet:"
    print d2

    # Compare d1 and d2:
    err = np.abs(d1 - d2).max()
    print "max difference:", err
```

Sample run:

```
dirichlet_sample:
[[ 0.38980834  0.4043844   0.20580726]
 [ 0.14076375  0.26906604  0.59017021]
 [ 0.64223074  0.26099934  0.09676991]
 [ 0.21880145  0.33775249  0.44344606]
 [ 0.39879859  0.40984454  0.19135688]
 [ 0.73976425  0.21467288  0.04556287]]
np.random.dirichlet:
[[ 0.38980834  0.4043844   0.20580726]
 [ 0.14076375  0.26906604  0.59017021]
 [ 0.64223074  0.26099934  0.09676991]
 [ 0.21880145  0.33775249  0.44344606]
 [ 0.39879859  0.40984454  0.19135688]
 [ 0.73976425  0.21467288  0.04556287]]
max difference: 5.55111512313e-17
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
y = np.array([np.random.dirichlet(x) for x in alphas])
```

for your list comprehension.  Otherwise you're simply passing a python list or tuple.  I imagine the reason `numpy.random.dirichlet` does not accept your list of alpha values is because it's not set up to - it already accepts an array, which it expects to have a dimension of `k`, as per the documentation.

Comment: This is nicer to look at, but no faster than OP's method.

Comment: Thanks, @BhajunSingh. Is there a way to do this with `np.fromiter` to minimize the overhead from the python `for` loop?

Comment: In fact, the loop comprehension is slower than OP's loop...  Not sure why.